# Accessing elements of a matrix row-wise versus column-wise

Tags: c, arrays

A matrix `A[i][j]` is given. If we want to add the elements of the matrix, which method is better and why?

1. column wise
2. row wise

From my point of view, row wise is better because in array representation elements are stored in contiguous memory locations so accessing them takes less  time.But since in RAM fetching every location takes equal time, does it matter?

Comment: What language are you using?  Different languages have different representations for matrices, and that affects how they should be used.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

**Take advantage of [Spatial Locality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality_of_reference)**

In C, matrixes are stored in r[ow-major order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-major_order). So if you access element `a[i][j]`, an access to element `a[i][j+1]` will be likely to hit the cache. No access to main memory will be performed. Caches are faster than main memory, so the access pattern does matter.

Of course, more factors must be taken into accout, such as write access / read access, write policy (write through, write back / write allocate , no write allocate), multilevel caches, and so on. But that seems an overkill for this question.

Have some fun with a profiling tool, such as [cachegrind](http://valgrind.org/info/tools.html#cachegrind), and see it for yourself.

For example, consider a dummy program accesing 4MB matrices. Check out the differences between the miss rates on each access pattern.

**column access**

```
$ cat col_major.c 
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

    size_t i,j;

    const size_t dim = 1024 ;

    int matrix [dim][dim];

    for (i=0;i< dim; i++){
        for (j=0;j <dim;j++){
            matrix[j][i]= i*j;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

$ valgrind --tool=cachegrind ./col_major 

==3228== D   refs:      10,548,665  (9,482,149 rd   + 1,066,516 wr)
==3228== D1  misses:     1,049,704  (      968 rd   + 1,048,736 wr)
==3228== L2d misses:     1,049,623  (      893 rd   + 1,048,730 wr)
==3228== D1  miss rate:        9.9% (      0.0%     +      98.3%  )
==3228== L2d miss rate:        9.9% (      0.0%     +      98.3%  )
```

**row access**

```
$ cat row_major.c 
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    size_t i,j;
    const size_t dim = 1024 ;
    int matrix [dim][dim];

    for (i=0;i< dim; i++)
        for (j=0;j <dim;j++)
            matrix[i][j]= i*j;

    return 0;
}

$ valgrind --tool=cachegrind ./row_major 

==3524== D   refs:      10,548,665  (9,482,149 rd   + 1,066,516 wr)
==3524== D1  misses:        66,664  (      968 rd   +    65,696 wr)
==3524== L2d misses:        66,583  (      893 rd   +    65,690 wr)
==3524== D1  miss rate:        0.6% (      0.0%     +       6.1%  )
==3524== L2d miss rate:        0.6% (      0.0%     +       6.1%  )
```

Comment: May I ask you if it was your intention to write `i< dim` and `j <dim`?

Comment: @Tom If you store your matrices column-major, you should iterate over them in column-major order, right? That would correct the cache misses I guess, or am I missing something?

Comment: This question is tagged C, and C stores multidimensional arrays in row major order. If you're using some other language that does column major order then yes, doing all of a column at once would be faster than doing all of a row at once.

Answer (score 3):

If the arrays are small it's not important.  If they're big, then the read time may be affected.  The big issue is the cache.  If you can't expect your complete matrix to be loaded into the cache at once, then you want to minimize the number of cache misses you encounter, because dealing with a cache miss is relatively time consuming.

If the arrays are really big, then you could take even bigger performance hits by causing more page swapping than necessary.

Answer (score 0):

For C, the best way to handle multidimensional arrays is:

```
int a[MAX_I][MAX_J];
for (i = 0; i < MAX_I; ++i) {
   for (j = 0; j < MAX_J; ++j) {
      /* process a[i][j] */
   }
}
```

The reason for this is that the C language handles arrays as pointers with offsets, see: [The C Programming Language](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131103628).