# Multi-Dimentional array iteration efficiency

Tags: c++, arrays

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Accessing elements of a matrix row-wise versus column-wise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4716125/accessing-elements-of-a-matrix-row-wise-versus-column-wise)

In C++, why is it more efficient to iterate through a multi-dimentional array like this:

```
// Iterate through the highest dimention last (k)
int num[10][10][10];

for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < 10; ++j)
    {
        for(int k = 0; k < 10; ++k)
        {
            cout << num[i][j][k];
        }
    }
}
```

Than like this:

```
// iterate through the highest dimension first (k)
int num[10][10][10];

for(int k = 0; k < 10; ++k)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < 10; ++j)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        {
            cout << num[i][j][k];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4716125/1328439

Comment: Not an exact duplicate, but the accepted answer is excellent and answers this question

Comment: yeah, the answer to that question answers mine too pretty much. So basically, it's faster because the elements in the last dimension of an array are stored one after the other in memory, so if your iterating through the last dimension, the elements are found right next to each other instead of jumping around memory like my last example? Also, is it like this for every language and every platform?

Comment: @cody For C it is portable across platforms, but it is not true for every language. A notable example is Fortran where multidimensional arrays are stored columnwise.

Answer (score 2):

This is because processor caches data, and arrays like `int array[n][m][k]` are represented in memory so, that first there are elements `array[0][0][0]` to `array[0][0][k - 1]` and so on. So if you iterate like in your first example, processor can load whole piece of memory in cache, but in the second example, processor can't copy "through" the memory.