# why is this matrix multiplication algorithm faster than the other?

Tags: c

```
int mmult_omp(double *c,
           double *a, int aRows, int aCols,
           double *b, int bRows, int bCols, int numThreads)
{
  for (i = 0; i < aRows; i++) {
for (j = 0; j < bCols; j++) {
  c[i*bCols + j] = 0;
}
for (k = 0; k < aCols; k++) {
  for (j = 0; j < bCols; j++) {
                c[i*bCols + j] += a[i*aCols + k] * b[k*bCols + j];
  }
}
```

}

```
for (i = 0; i < aRows; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < bCols; j++) {
    c[i*bCols + j] = 0;
    for (k = 0; k < aCols; k++) {
    c[i*bCols + j] += a[i*aCols + k] *  b[k*bCols + j];
  }
}
```

}

Why is the first algorithm faster than the second?
I’ve used C’s time library and the first algorithm is objectively faster than the second. Why is that?

Comment: The first algorithm accesses the memory in strides of 8 bytes; the other accesses it in strides of 8*bCols bytes. Hence, the first one has better locality.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accessing elements of a matrix row-wise versus column-wise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4716125/accessing-elements-of-a-matrix-row-wise-versus-column-wise)

Comment: @eozd thank you. I wrote out the first row calculation for both algorithms and clearly all matrices are being accessed sequentially in the first, and in the second b is being accessed in increments of bCols. Thank you so much.

Comment: By the way the performance can still be substantially improved

Comment: @harold I’ve already done so with openMp. I can cut the tome by a forth on a 4 core CPU.

Comment: Even more than that. This code by design cannot reach peak FLOPS, it has too many loads/FMA and doesn't implement tiling.

Answer (score -1):

This code is very hard to understand. I had to copy it and reformat it to see what loops were what. I'm not really sure why one is faster but here's a great resource to see why.

Here are links to inspect the assembly output:

[link for #1](https://godbolt.org/z/XYgLq_) 
[link for #2](https://godbolt.org/z/SoZawj)

Comment: Apologies. I wrote this on my phone at a restaurant because I’m dying for an answer. But I receive one so thanks/