# Is there a efficiency difference between a single dimensional array and a 2 dimensional array (matrix)?

Tags: c, arrays, multithreading, multidimensional-array

I'm currently developing board like game in C for university. And the teacher provided some code and the way he stores the board in memory is with a single dimensional array, the board has 16 elements (4x4 board) and row 0 is in the positions [0, 3], row 2 is in positions [4, 7].. etc. He also uses the functions below to convert 2 dimensional coordenates (i,j) into a 1 dimensional coordenate in order to correctly access the right board position (functions below). This board will be managed by multiple threads, maybe this will help with multi-threaded synchronization?
And my question is: Is it less efficient to store the board in a 2 dimensional array (a matrix) with 4 rows and 4 columns?

```
int linearConv(int i, int j){
  return j*dim+i;
}
char* getBoardPlaceStr(int i, int j){
  return board[linearConv(i, j)].v;
}
```

PS: Also, is accessing an arrray like array[0], dereferencing a pointer (ie *pointer), acessing a struct member (ie struct.member or sutuct->member) atomic operations that do not need critical regions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This board will be managed by multiple threads, maybe this will help
>   with multi-threaded synchronization?

I see no reason to expect that.

> And my question is: Is it less
>   efficient to store the board in a 2 dimensional array (a matrix) with
>   4 rows and 4 columns?

No, in C it is no less efficient to store the board in a *bona fide* 2D array.  The layout in memory is indistinguishable from the 1D layout you describe, and the indexing computations for retrieving elements are thus completely equivalent to those in the code presented.

The same is not true of some other languages, such as Java, where each dimension requires a separate pointer dereference, and arrays, as objects, have additional associated data and metadata beyond just the elements.  A data structure like that can be formed in C, too, but although it can be indexed as if it were a multi-dimensional array, its structure and layout is in fact quite different.

Although the 1D and 2D cases you're asking about are *logically* equivalent, it is perhaps worth noting that in the unlikely event that the compiler chose not to inline calls to `linearConv()` in the specific code you present, interposing that function would make the 1D version a bit less efficient than the 2D.

> Also, is accessing an arrray like array[0], dereferencing a pointer
>   (ie *pointer), acessing a struct member (ie struct.member or
>   sutuct->member) atomic operations that do not need critical regions?

No, none of those are atomic in the sense you mean.

Answer (score 5):

> Is it less efficient to store the board in a 2 dimensional array (a matrix) with 4 rows and 4 columns?

Both:

```
T board[4][4];
```

And:

```
T board[4 * 4];
```

Have the same size, alignment and layout. Generally, elements in any-dimensional arrays are stored contiguously with no gaps (otherwise pointer arithmetic would not work).

Accessing elements using `[j][i]` and `[j * 4 + i]` does the same calculation in assembly.

In other words, there are no performance or space differences between these two.

Comment: ... and the pointer arithmetic involved in evaluating `board[j][i]` guarantees that it's 100% equivalent to `board[j*4 + i]` even by the word of the standard.

Comment: @user3707533 Note that this applies to a "true" multi-dimensional array. Further dimensions may also be implemented using arrays of pointers (and in some other languages it is necessary to do so), in which case following those pointers does in fact add overhead. I would also suggest an exercise of trying to convert the original code to use a 2D array – my guess would be that in doing so you would discover that it may actually turn out more complicated (e.g., you might have to repeat the `dim` in quite many places, as opposed to just inside `linearConv`).

Comment: @Arkku I like that you call the standard built-in C and C++ arrays _true_ arrays.

Comment: Thank you, you were very clarifying

Answer (score 3):

The elements of an array are next to each other in memory for an arbitrary dimension.

However the **access** to these elements has a big influence on efficiency for example for caching purposes, directly speaking.

In computer science exists something called the principle of locality. Either in space or time.

Regarding arrays we got the locality of space which says that accessing an element at `arr[1][1]` will **probably** result in an access to the element `arr[1][2]`, too.

Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4716339/3811394) on how access of arrays (row-/columnwise) may affect the efficiency.

Comment: How does this address the OP's question, which is about the *relative* efficiency of 1D- and 2D-array access?