# Why writing by column is slow in two dimensional array in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, algorithm

I have two-dimensional array when I am adding values by column it write very slowly (less than 300x):

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            TwoDimArrayPerfomrance.GetByColumns();
            TwoDimArrayPerfomrance.GetByRows();
        }
    }

    class TwoDimArrayPerfomrance
    {

        public static void GetByRows()
        {
            int maxLength = 20000;
            int[,] a = new int[maxLength, maxLength];
            DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
          
            Console.WriteLine("The current time is: " + dt.ToString());

            //fill value
            for (int i = 0; i < maxLength; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < maxLength; j++)
                {

                    a[i, j] = i + j;
                }
            }


            DateTime end = DateTime.Now;
            Console.WriteLine("Total: " + end.Subtract(dt).TotalSeconds);

        }

        public static void GetByColumns()
        {
            int maxLength = 20000;
            int[,] a = new int[maxLength, maxLength];
            DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
            Console.WriteLine("The current time is: " + dt.ToString());
            for (int i = 0; i < maxLength; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < maxLength; j++)
                {

                    a[j, i] = j + i;
                }
            }
            DateTime end = DateTime.Now;
            Console.WriteLine("Total: " + end.Subtract(dt).TotalSeconds);

        }

    }
```

**The Column vice taking around 4.2 seconds
while Row wise taking 1.53**

Comment: Cache proximity probably... Have you run the program without the debugger in release mode? (CTRL+F5 in Visual  Studio)? Tried doing `TwoDimArrayPerfomrance.GetByColumns(); TwoDimArrayPerfomrance.GetByRows(); TwoDimArrayPerfomrance.GetByColumns(); TwoDimArrayPerfomrance.GetByRows();` to see if it is a warmup problem? What version of .NET Core/.NET Framework and 32 or 64 bits? Microbenchmarking is an art, a complex art.

Comment: Ah and bidi arrays are like '90 airstyles... Not longer trendy. It is suggested to use jagged arrays (`int[][]`)

Comment: Please, use `StopWatch` instead of `DateTime` when measuring time spent.

Comment: @DmitryBychenko thanks i am now using StopWatch but still the same time its taking

Comment: @xanatos when i am calling it the second time then the second iteration takes 3 seconds instead 4.

Comment: @xanatos I am using .net Core 3.1

Comment: As mentioned by others, it is due to caching of the adjacent memory locations. This is also explained here  - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4716125/accessing-elements-of-a-matrix-row-wise-versus-column-wise, in the context of matrices. Different languages have different implementations, so will yield different results.

Answer (score 3):

It is the "cache proximity" problem mentioned in the first comment. There are memory caches that any data must go through to be accessed by the CPU. Those caches store blocks of memory, so if you are first accessing memory N and then memory N+1 then cache is not changed. But if you first access memory N and then memory N+M (where M is big enough) then new memory block must be added to the cache. When you add new block to the cache some existing block must be removed. If you then have to access this removed block then you have inefficiency in the code.

Answer (score 0):

I concur fully with what @Dialecticus wrote... I'll just add that there are bad ways to write a microbenchark, and there are worse ways. There are many things to do when microbenchmarking. Remembering to run in Release mode without the debugger attached, remembering that there is a GC, and that it is better if it runs when you want it to run, and not casually when you are benchmarking, remembering that sometimes the code is compiled only after it is executed at least once, so at least a round of full warmup is a good idea... and so on... There is even a full library about benchmarking (https://benchmarkdotnet.org/articles/overview.html) that is used by Microscot .NET Core teams to check that there are no speed regressions on the code they write.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        if (Debugger.IsAttached)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Warning, debugger attached!");
        }

#if DEBUG
        Console.WriteLine("Warning, Debug version!");
#endif

        Console.WriteLine($"Running at {(Environment.Is64BitProcess ? 64 : 32)}bits");

        Console.WriteLine(RuntimeInformation.FrameworkDescription);

        Process.GetCurrentProcess().PriorityClass = ProcessPriorityClass.High;

        Console.WriteLine();

        const int MaxLength = 10000;

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Round {i + 1}:");

            TwoDimArrayPerfomrance.GetByRows(MaxLength);
            GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

            TwoDimArrayPerfomrance.GetByColumns(MaxLength);
            GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
}

class TwoDimArrayPerfomrance
{

    public static void GetByRows(int maxLength)
    {
        int[,] a = new int[maxLength, maxLength];

        Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();

        //fill value
        for (int i = 0; i < maxLength; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < maxLength; j++)
            {

                a[i, j] = i + j;
            }
        }

        sw.Stop();

        Console.WriteLine($"By Rows, size {maxLength} * {maxLength}, {sw.ElapsedMilliseconds / 1000.0:0.00} seconds");

        // So that the assignment isn't optimized out, we do some fake operation on the array
        for (int i = 0; i < maxLength; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < maxLength; j++)
            {
                if (a[i, j] == int.MaxValue)
                {
                    throw new Exception();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void GetByColumns(int maxLength)
    {
        int[,] a = new int[maxLength, maxLength];

        Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();

        //fill value
        for (int i = 0; i < maxLength; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < maxLength; j++)
            {

                a[j, i] = i + j;
            }
        }

        sw.Stop();

        Console.WriteLine($"By Columns, size {maxLength} * {maxLength}, {sw.ElapsedMilliseconds / 1000.0:0.00} seconds");

        // So that the assignment isn't optimized out, we do some fake operation on the array
        for (int i = 0; i < maxLength; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < maxLength; j++)
            {
                if (a[i, j] == int.MaxValue)
                {
                    throw new Exception();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Ah... and multi-dimensional arrays of the type `FooType[,]` [went the way of the dodo](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/go_the_way_of_the_dodo) with .NET 3.5, when LINQ came out and it didn't support them. You should use jagged arrays `FooType[][]`.

Answer (score 0):

If you try to map your two dimensional array to a one dimensional one, it might be a bit easier to see what is going on.

The mapping gives

```
var a = int[maxLength * maxLength];
```

Now the lookup calculation is up to you.

```
for (int i = 0; i < maxLength; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < maxLength; j++)
    {
        //var rowBased = j + i * MaxLength;
        var colBased = i + j * MaxLength;

        //a[rowBased] = i + j;
        a[colBased] = i + j;
    }
}
```

So observe the following

- On column based lookup the number of multiplications is 20.000 * 20.000 multiplications, because *j* changes for every loop
- On row based lookup the *i * MaxLength* is compiler optimised and only happens 20.000 times.
- Now that **a** is a one dimensional array it's also easier to see how the memory is being accessed. On row based index the memory is access sequentially, where as column based access is almost random and depending on the size of the array the overhead will vary as you have seen it.

Looking a bit on what BenchmarkDotNet produces

```
BenchmarkDotNet=v0.12.1, OS=Windows 10.0.19042
AMD Ryzen 9 3900X, 1 CPU, 24 logical and 12 physical cores
.NET Core SDK=5.0.101
```

| Method | MaxLength | Mean | Error | StdDev |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| GetByRows | 100 | 23.60 us | 0.081 us | 0.076 us |
| GetByColumns | 100 | 23.74 us | 0.357 us | 0.334 us |
| GetByRows | 1000 | 2,333.20 us | 13.150 us | 12.301 us |
| GetByColumns | 1000 | 2,784.43 us | 10.027 us | 8.889 us |
| GetByRows | 10000 | 238,599.37 us | 1,592.838 us | 1,412.009 us |
| GetByColumns | 10000 | 516,771.56 us | 4,272.849 us | 3,787.770 us |
| GetByRows | 50000 | 5,903,087.26 us | 13,822.525 us | 12,253.308 us |
| GetByColumns | 50000 | 19,623,369.45 us | 92,325.407 us | 86,361.243 us |

You will see that while *MaxLength* is reasonable small, the differences are almost negligible (100x100) and (1000x1000), because I expect that the CPU can keep the allocated two dimensional array in the fast access memory cache and the differences are only related to the number of multiplications.

When the matrix becomes larger, then the CPU can no longer keep all allocated memory in its internal cache and we will start to see cache-misses and fetching memory from the external memory storage instead, which is always going to be a lot slower.

That *overhead* just increases as the size of the matrix grows.

Comment: This maybe an exellent appraoch to solve the issue but my question why it is taking more time? The logic behind. Anyway, i will try it.

Comment: It's taking longer time because 1) The array lookup when column based have to do 400 million multiplications compared to 20.000 for row based. 2) Row based memory access is sequential and requires much less memory reads and CPU cache invalidations.